# Is there any way to differentiate sessions of each client in cassandra QueryHandler?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

My aim is to log unique queries per session by writing custom QueryHandler implementation as logging all queries causes performance hit in our case.

Consider the case : If a user connected to cassandra cluster with java client and performs "select * from users where id = ?" 100 times.
And another user connected from cqlsh and performed same query 50 times. so i want to log only two queries in this case. For that i need a unique session id per login.

Cassandra provides below interface where all requests lands up but none of its apis provide any sessionId to differentiate between two different session described in above case.

```
org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryHandler
```

Note: I am able to get remoteaddress/port but i want some id which is created when user logged in and get destroyed when he disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

In `queryState.getClientState().getRemoteAddress()` the address + port will be unique per tcp connection in the sessions pool. There can be multiple concurrent requests over each connection though, and a session can have multiple connections per host. There is also no guarantee the same tcp connection will be used from one request to another on client side.

However a single session cannot be connected as 2 different users (part of the initialization of connection) so the scenario you described isn't possible from the same Session object perspective. I think just using the address as the key for uniqueness will be all you can do given how the protocol/driver works. It will at least dedup things a little.

Are you actually processing your logging inline or are you pushing it off async? If using logback it should be using async appender but if your posting events synchronously to another server, might be better just to throw all the events on a queue and let it do the deduping in another thread so you don't hurt latency.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the reply. i believe getRemoteAddress() wont differentiate in case there are different client connecting to cassandra from same machine as host and port will be same for all . Currently i was not using asynch appender however i will try that as well. asynch appender also has some cons in terms of memory  and cpu utilization so i need to keep those points in mind wile configuring it. Initially i was planning to  test the performance with synch appender only.

Comment: Port would not be the same, the destination port would be 9042 but each tcp connection would have a unique source port so the kernel can differentiate which goes to which connection. However a Session does represent a pool of connections so it can span multiple, but it would be a start. I would recommend the async, the memory concerns can be covered by making it droppable queue (this is C* does for tracing executor for example).

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13983 (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/pull/169) might be of interest to you

Comment: Thanks Chris for your valuable comments. I will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: Hi Chris, are you aware of any way to differentiate between primary node and replica in org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryHandler ?  Right now if cluster has replication factor 3 then the one insert request goes to all 3 node's QueryHandler. I see an api ClientState.isInternal but that does not tell the same, it is for interal system keyspace ops.

Comment: I think this goes to primary node only as i was sending batch queries  with multiple values so it might be distributing to other primary node.  Correct me if i am wrong.